# Getting current table data from Ant Design Table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant design table for displaying some data. New data arrives every one second. When user clicks on button, I need to export current table data to XSL.

I'm getting current data in this way:

```
onChange={(pagination, filter, sorter, currentTable) => this.onTableChange(filter, sorter, currentTable)}.
```

This thing works and gets me good and filtered data, but when I get new data, I can't get those new data because this function is not triggered while none of the filters or sort settings didn't change. Is there any way to get current table data without dummy changing filter to trigger onChange function?

Title and footer return only current page data.

Code show here

```
 {    <Table
                    dataSource={this.props.data}
                    rowKey={(record) => { return record.id}}
                    columns={this.state.Columns}
                    pagination={this.state.pageSizeOptions}
                    rowClassName={(record) => { return 
this.getRowClassNames(record) }}
                    expandedRowKeys={ this.state.expandedRowKeys }
                    expandedRowRender={record => { return 
this.getEventsRows(record) }}
                    onExpand={(expanded, record) => { 
this.onExpandRow(expanded, record.id) }}
                    expandRowByClick={false}
                    onChange={(pagination, filter, sorter, currentTable) 
=> this.onTableChange(filter, sorter, currentTable)}
                />
 }
```

Comment: it is hard to understand your requirement, can you be clear?

Comment: I'm sorry. I need to get current filtered data because I need export that data to XSL table. For example, I set some filter, sorter, or pagination, so onChange is triggered and I can get current filtered data. But when I get new data in this.props.data, like in code above, I can get new data, but not filtered with previously set settings because onChange triggers only on pagination, sorter and filter change. My question is how to get current filtered data, without dummy changing page and returning to it. Hope this explains.
Thank You.

Comment: How about blocking sort and filter options till data is completely loaded. Showing columns without those features. Once you get the complete data from backend  then you can enable those features to columns. so whenever user clicks it then onchange triggers....
Assuming you are going to export table when complete data is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can store pagination, sorter and filter data in your component state. Also you can pass these params to your redux state and store there. If you can share your code, i can provide more specific answers.

Below you can find my solution for permanent filter. I was sending filter params to API and get filtered data. If you want to filter it in the component, you can use component lifecycle or render method.

```
onTableChange(pagination, filter, sorter){
    const { params, columns } = this.state;

    /** You can do any custom thing you want here. Below i update sort type in my state and pass it to my redux function */
    if(sorter.order != null)
        params.ordering = (sorter.order === 'descend' ? "-" : "")+ sorter.columnKey.toString();

    this.setState({params});
    this.props.listUsers(this.state.params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have taken either columns, datasource varibale as object instead of array.
write
`this.state.someVariable=[]` 
instead of
`this.state.someVariable = {}`